# Count and sort pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column 'code' which I have sorted based on frequency.
In order to see what each code means, there is also a column 'note'.
For each counting/grouping of the 'code' column, I display the first note that is attached to the first 'code'

```
df.groupby('code')['note'].agg(['count', 'first']).sort_values('count', ascending=False)
```

Now my question is, how do I display only those rows that have frequency of e.g. >= 30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `query` call before you sort. Also, if you only want those rows EQUALing < insert frequency here >, `sort_values` isn't needed (right?!).

```
df.groupby('code')['note'].agg(['count', 'first']).query('count == 30')
```

---

If the question is for all groups with AT LEAST < insert frequency here >, then

```
( 
   df.groupby('code')
     .note.agg(['count', 'first'])
     .query('count >= 30')
     .sort_values('count', ascending=False)
)
```

Why do I use `query`? It's a lot easier to pipe and chain with it.

Comment: Oh.. I asked the question wrong.. I meant frequency with at least 30. As, always, thanks! :)

Comment: @AnonX It becomes count >= 30, and then add `sort_values` again. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter your result accordingly:

```
grp = grp[grp['count'] >= 30]
```

**Example with data**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'code': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                   'note': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A',
                            'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B'] })

res = df.groupby('code')['note'].agg(['count', 'first']).sort_values('count', ascending=False)

#       count first
# code             
# 2         5     C
# 3         5     B
# 1         4     A

res2 = res[res['count'] >= 5]

#       count first
# code             
# 2         5     C
# 3         5     B
```